# Find the The sum of all even positive divisors of $1000$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

The sum of all even positive divisors of $1000$ is what?

My solution goes like this :

> The factorization of $1000=2^3.5^3$. Now, we can choose one $2$ and zero $5$ to build an even factor, we can choose two $2$'s and zero $5$'s to build an even factor; we can choose three $2$'s and zero $5$'s to build an even factor; next, we can choose one  $2$'s and two $5$'s to build an even factor; we can choose one $2$'s and three $5$'s to build an even factor; we can choose one $2$'s and three $5$'s to build an even factor, ....continuing in this way, we get, the total number of ways is:
> $$\binom{3}{1} + \binom{3}{2} + \binom{3}{3} + \binom{3}{1}\binom{3}{1} + \binom{3}{1}\binom{3}{2} + \binom{3}{1}\binom{3}{3} + \ldots + \binom{3}{3}\binom{3}{3}$$

I know a lot of answers are available to this question in lots of sites including this one too! But I solved it in a method. Can anyone please point out whether this method is valid or not? I just want to verify this solution. Also, I did not find this method incorporated anywhere, neither here nor in any other site.  If it is done like this in this site, I am unaware of it, but please do explain whether this method is valid or not?

Comment: You have to sum up the even divisors , not to count them.

Comment: @Peter ohh... yup ur correct...Thank you so much!

Comment: An elegant solution uses the divisor-sum formula for $1000$ and for $125$ and subtracts those values. But here you can as well just enumerate the even divisors and add them.

Comment: @Peter can u please explain why divisor-sum formula for 1000 and for 125 and subtracting  those values gives the required sum ? I did not quite get it...

Comment: Well, the odd divisors are exactly the divisors of $125$ (no $2$ in the prime factorization)

Comment: @Peter ohh.. i do get it now...Thanks a lot!

Comment: Formatting tip:  Use `$\binom{n}{k}$` to obtain $\binom{n}{k}$ rather than using `$n \choose k$`.   That will allow you to write one formula rather than stringing multiple formulas in a line.  For instance, type `$\binom{3}{1} + \binom{3}{2} + \binom{3}{3}$` to produce $\binom{3}{1} + \binom{3}{2} + \binom{3}{3}$.